# Difference between two methods in django

Tags: django, django-views

What's difference between two methods and which is better for long run ? Is there any advantage one over other?

To add a staff:

(1st Method)

`views.py`

```
def add_staff(request):
    return render(request, 'hod_template/add_staff_template.html')

def add_staff_save(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return HttpResponse('Method not allowed')
    else:
        first_name = request.GET.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.GET.get('last_name')
        username = request.GET.get('username')
        email = request.GET.get('email')
        password = request.GET.get('password')
        address = request.GET.get('address')
        try:
            user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email, last_name=last_name, first_name=first_name, user_type=2)
            user.staffs.address = address
            user.save() 
            messages.success(request, 'Staff Added Successfully')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/add_staff')
        except:
            messages.error(request, 'Failed to Add Staff')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/add_staff')
```

`urls.py`

```
    path('add_staff/', add_staff),
    path('add_staff_save/', add_staff_save),
```

`add_staff.html`

```
    <form role="form" action="/add_staff_save">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
            </div>

            <!-- same for first_name, last_name, username, address --> 
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add Staff</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

(2nd Method)

make a form in forms.py of all fields first_name, last_name, username, address
and then call in view and validate it.
`forms.py`

```
    class StaffForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Staff
            fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'address')
```

`views.py`

```
def add_staff(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StaffForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.success(request, 'Staff Added Successfully')
            form.save()
    else: 
        form = StaffForm()
    return render(request, 'staff.html', {'form':form})
```

`urls.py`
 `path('add_staff/', add_staff),`

`staff.html`

```
    <form role="form" action="/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }} <!-- render form as paragraph -->
    </form>
```

Both methods work well and staff model have all the required field.
Sorry for long question since its getting too long I'm not adding staff model. If you need plz let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd method is better than 1st one. 2nd method give more flexibility you only have to make a form in forms.py and you can use it in different locations while for 1st method you have to use 2 urls just to show form and save it . Also you can use filters like `crispy_forms_tags` on form as `{{ form|crispy }}`. So obviously in long run 2nd method is better.

Answer (score 1):

of course the second method is much way better than the first one
because you should do cleaning and validation in other files like forms.py in each individual section

and also you can add more options and other things that maybe will be useful after a time
and you should be aware of that and predict some changes for improvement too!
and with making forms and use generics , you will write less code than doing it by yourself in hardcode in views.

so don't hesitate and choose method2

Comment: can I use bootstrap on 2nd method ?